# What does tsc --build do when you are not using any project references?

Tags: typescript

Just to see what would happen, I ran [`tsc --build`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) on a project that uses no project references. To my surprise, it ran and completed fine. I thought it would be a warning/error since the build flag was created in context with project references.

My question: if the project uses no project references, what's the difference between running `tsc` and `tsc --build`?

Comment: Both are essentially equivalent. There's no real difference in the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use-case, they are basically the same if you have no project references in your `tsconfig.json` file, so `tsc` command will suffice.

Using `tsc --build` becomes more valuable as your project grows and you want to manage dependencies and build order across multiple projects efficiently (most commonly found in **monorepos**)